# Destruction for type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
export type Props = {
  value: string;
};
```

and component:

```
export const Component = (props: Props) => (
  <Rate>
    <RateValue weight="medium" size={22}>
      {props.value}
    </Styled.RateValue>
  </Rate>
);
```

how can I use desctruction for `{props.value}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export const Component = ({ value }: Props) => (
  <Rate>
    <RateValue weight="medium" size={22}>
      {value}
    </Styled.RateValue>
  </Rate>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using react? You can also do this:

```js
export const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({ value }) => (
  <Rate>
    <RateValue weight="medium" size={22}>
      {props.value}
    </Styled.RateValue>
  </Rate>
);
```